# Removing Deployable Dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, deployment

After adding `"Deployable Dependencies"` to my `ASP MVC3` project I am getting a 404 error looking for an `/Account/Login` page which my site does not have.

After doing some research I see that this is an issue with the ASP.NET Razor dependencies that were added. However, after scouring the internet I cannot find one resource that tells me how to remove these dependencies.

Is is as simple as deleting the bin folder the `dlls` are stored in or is there another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in MVC 3 which often surfaces as soon as you deploy (and add deployable dependancies). We dealt with it recently.

The answer is to add the following app settings

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" /
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/LogOn" />
```